# How to identify the empty fields in a file and replace with value and display only few columns in unix

Tags: unix

I tried the below command but failed it is not given expected output. I want to replace blank column field with NA in file.

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$1==$1!=""?$1:"NA"}' file.txt
```

Please help me in the same.

Comment: You should always show some example input and the expected and actual output. You probably mean `$1=$1!=""?$1:"NA"` (Assignment is a single `=`, not `==`), and you forgot to `print` the resulting line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{ if ($1 == "") { $1 = "NA" }; print }' file.txt
```